# Using input() to quit

Tags: python, loops, user-input

I'm a pretty new programmer and have been working with Python 3 for a few weeks. I tried making a little magic 8 ball program where you get an answer to a question and it asks if you want to play again. however no matter what I enter it never quits and keeps looping. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#Magic 8 Ball V2
import random
import time

class Magic8ball:

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def getanswer(self):
        responselist = ['The future looks bright!', 'Not too good...', 'Its a fact!',
                        'The future seems cloudy', 'Ask again later', 'Doesnt look too good for you',
                        'How would i know?', 'Maybe another time']
        cho = random.randint(0, 7)
        print ('Getting answer...')
        time.sleep(2)
        print (responselist[cho])

purple = Magic8ball('Purple')
blue = Magic8ball('Blue')
black = Magic8ball('Black')

while True:
    print ('Welcome to the magic 8 ball sim part 2')
    input('Ask your question:')
    black.getanswer()
    print ('Would you like to play again?')
    choice = ' '
    choice = input()
    if choice != 'y' or choice != 'yes':
        break
```

Comment: Your Boolean logic is wrong...

Comment: If you are never quitting, then something else is going on.  As written, it should always *exit*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things wrong with your code:

**1)**

```
choice = ' '
choice = input()
```

No need for the first line, you are immediately overriding it.

**2)**

```
print ('Would you like to play again?')
choice = input()
```

Instead of this, use just `input("Would you like to play again?")`

**3)**
The logic on the line of `if choice != 'y' or choice != 'yes':` is wrong.

In my opinion it would be better if you did this:

```
if choice not in ("y", "yes"):
```

This would make it really clear what you are trying to do.

Also, you might want to consider using `choice.lower()` just for the convenience of the users. So that `Yes` still counts.

Comment: `if choice not in set(["y", "yes"])` is faster still.

Comment: @RoadieRich How come? `set()` just does some additional operation (checking for dublication and creating a new object) after it creates the list, adding more overhead. I will actually change the list into a tuple since it's a bit faster as far as I remember.

Comment: `item in set(...)` is amortized `O(1)`, because it hashes values.  `item in list(...)` is `O(n)`, as it needs to check every element in the list.

Comment: @RoadieRich come on, the overhead of creating the set is way more than the tiny efficiency (if there even is, since hashing takes time) of a hash table on 2 elements.

Comment: You mentioned `not item in...` vs `item not in...`, that difference is even smaller, especially if you move the set creation outside the loop.

Comment: @AmitGold Working now! Awesome and thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tamilist you might also use `choice.lower()` for the convenience of the users.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#exit) to quit the shell.

Also, as @jonrsharpe notes, you want `and` instead of `or` on this line:

`if choice != 'y' or choice != 'yes':`

That's because if the user supplies `'y`', the program will do two checks: First, it checks if `choice != 'y'`, which is false. Then, because you are using `or`, it checks if `choice != 'yes'`, which is *true*. Therefore, the program will break out of the while loop no matter what the user inputs.